# Filemaker no multiplica campos

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo un problema serio con Filemaker.

Por alguna razón, no quiere hacer operaciones incluso dentro de la misma tabla.

Los dos campos están en la misma tabla y son de tipo numero.

[image: Es Filemaker Pro 16]

Les agradezco su respuesta.

Comment: He probado multiplicar 2 números que están en campos mediante un campo cálculo y todo bien, si aún tienes dificultades me escribes y te ayudo

Comment: Tal vez a estas alturas ya resolviste el problema.
Puedes intentar cambiando el campo importe a Calculo y especificar que el resultado de la operación es numerico.
En la imagen que compartes intenta desactivada la validación de No evaluar si todos los campos indicados están vacíos.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar desmarcar la opción 'No evaluar si todos los campos indicados están vacíos', después de esto recordar que el campo se actualizará solo al manipular los dos campos indicados, pero no es un campo calculado, es número con cálculo por lo cual no tiene activador directo, si pruebas usar el evento con una modificación en la tabla puede que sea más fácil que se ejecute cuando lo corras ejemplo:

crear campo update - timestamp - 'modify timestamp' por defecto

en tu campo de la BD IF(update; Cantidad * Precio ; Importe )

Recordar que es probable que si estás haciendo ese cálculo desde una tabla encabezada sobre una tabla detalle puede que no se ejecute correctamente al no ser calculado, por eso es recomendable, al menos a mi parecer, hacer este tipo de cálculos en un script que se ejecute como trigger dentro de ambos campos de cantidad y precio en tu layout.